# Webview running on wrong thread exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, webview

Initially was loading a link in webview since this is a sample app. Work fine till api 4.1 .Throws an exception when loading the same in ver 4.3 onwards.

Code:

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (loadThisUrl != null) {
                simpBrowser.loadUrl(loadThisUrl);
            }

        }
});
```

The Logcat:

```
03-24 10:45:27.580: A/libc(27538): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00006b92 (code=-6),    thread 27568 (e.simplebrowser)
```

I tried running this on ui thread still the same issue. previously i would simply load the url and it seem to work. any points on how or where i'm going wrong will be very helpful.